# How add two characters with quotes separated by comma in case statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a scenario where i have select two characters 'P','E' from case statement when case validation is successful i.e., 'ALL' = 'ALL'
Below is the thing i'm trying to achieve:

```
select location,
grade,
City,
process_flag,
from table_v 
where process_flag in (
Case 
when :process_type = 'Processed' then 'P'
when :process_type = 'ERROR' then 'E'
when :process_type = 'ALL' then 'P','E'
ELSE process_flag
END;
```

Process_type can be passed as 'Processed', 'ERROR', 'ALL'

how can achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `or`ed conditions:

```
where 
       :process_type = 'Processed' and process_flag = 'P'
    or :process_type = 'ERROR'     and process_flag = 'E'
    or :process_type = 'ALL'       and process_flag in ('P', 'E')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple values in the `IN` clause:

```sql
WHERE ( :process_type, process_flag ) IN (
        ( 'Processed', 'P' ),
        ( 'ERROR',     'E' ),
        ( 'ALL',       'P' ),
        ( 'ALL',       'E' ),
      )
```

and if you want to match the `ELSE` clause of your `CASE` statement then:

```sql
WHERE ( :process_type, process_flag ) IN (
        ( 'Processed', 'P' ),
        ( 'ERROR',     'E' ),
        ( 'ALL',       'P' ),
        ( 'ALL',       'E' ),
      )
OR    :process_type NOT IN ( 'Processed', 'ERROR', 'ALL' )
```